# Insertar elemento en vector ordenado C

Tags: c

Andaría buscando una función que inserte un numero en un arreglo ya ordenado de forma ascendente.
Por ejemplo si yo tengo un arreglo de 5 elementos pre inicializados con: 1,3,5,7,9

Y le quiero insertar un 4, deberia quedar 1,3,4,5,7

Eliminando el 9.
¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Si, alguna solución existe. ¿Has intentado alguna hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1):

Lo he hecho de esta manera, seguramente falte optimizarlo pero esto es lo que logre.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void ejercicio23(int tam, int * s, int bus);
int main()
{
    int vector[]={ 1, 5, 7, 9, 11},
    bus=2,
    i,
    tam=sizeof(vector)/sizeof(int);
ejercicio23(tam,vector,bus);
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%d\t",vector[i]);
return(0);
}
void ejercicio23(int tam, int * s, int bus)
{
int i,
    aux,
    auxx,
    salir=0;
while((*s) && salir==0)
{

   if(bus<(*s))
    {
        aux=(*s);
        *s=bus;
        s++;
        while(*s && tam)
        {
            auxx=aux+(*s);
            *s=aux;
            aux=auxx-(*s);
            tam--;
            s++;
        }
        salir=1;
    }
    tam--;
    s++;
    }
}
```